# Call Android method without running whole Android-App

Tags: android, gdb, dynamic-analysis

I want to ask if somebody is aware of tools/projects which are similar to the *Appcall* feature of IDA Pro[1] for Android Apps?

I'm looking for the possibility to run certain methods detected in the smali code without running the whole APK.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

[1] http://www.hexblog.com/?p=113

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/CalebFenton/simplify and this http://calebfenton.github.io/2016/04/30/dalvik-virtual-execution-with-smalivm/

Comment: Just to clarify: `Appcall` requires you to run the binary before allowing you to call its functions. It won't work statically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to write a separate application that dynamically loads the dex file from the app that you are interested in using [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html), allowing you to construct classes and call methods from that dex file.

You can get the path to the other apk using PackageManager.getApplicationInfo(). The [sourceDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir,) field of the returned ApplicationInfo object will have the path to the apk.

Comment: Thanks for your fast help :-) This sounds like an appropriate solution :-)